# How to insert Timestamp value in Cloud spanner using python client libraries

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to insert csv file reading row by row to replace Null with None, but when it comes to timestamp column it is raising error invalid value for column expects Timestamp

I am trying to insert csv file into GCP Cloud Spanner reading row by row to replace Null with None, but when it comes to timestamp column it is raising error invalid value for column expects Timestamp

Comment: Would you mind sharing the exact error message that you are getting? And could you also share the code that you are executing? Knowing what statement that you are executing (or the mutation that you are creating) will be very helpful in understanding where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think the format of your timestamp may not match. The format for timestamp to enter data in spanner is the ISO format
Example: '2023-02-14T05:19:00.790695Z'
For further reference you can check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type).
For python specifically the datetime.datetime api can also be used in this manner:

```
example_timestamp = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).isoformat() + "Z"
```